# error TS2345: Argument of type 'T' is not assignable to parameter of type 'object'

Tags: typescript, typescript2.2

The code below was working fine with TypeScript 2.1.6:

```
function create<T>(prototype: T, pojo: Object): T {
    // ...
    return Object.create(prototype, descriptors) as T;
}
```

After updating to TypeScript 2.2.1, I am getting the following error:

> error TS2345: Argument of type 'T' is not assignable to parameter of
>   type 'object'.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Change signature of the function, so that generic type `T` extends type `object`, introduced in Typescript 2.2. Use this syntax - `<T extends object>`:

```
function create<T extends object>(prototype: T, pojo: Object): T {
    ...
    return Object.create(prototype, descriptors) as T;
}
```

Answer (score 12):

The signature for `Object.create` was changed in TypeScript 2.2.

Prior to TypeScript 2.2, the type definition for `Object.create` was:

```
create(o: any, properties: PropertyDescriptorMap): any;
```

But as you point out, [TypeScript 2.2 introduced](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What%27s-new-in-TypeScript#object-type) the `object` type:

> TypeScript did not have a type that represents the non-primitive type, i.e. any thing that is not `number` | `string` | `boolean` | `symbol` | `null` | `undefined`. Enter the new object type.
>
> With object type, APIs like Object.create can be better represented.

The type definition for `Object.create` was changed to:

```
create(o: object, properties: PropertyDescriptorMap): any;
```

So the generic type `T` in your example is not assignable to `object` unless the compiler is told that `T` extends `object`.

Prior to version 2.2 the compiler would not catch an error like this:

```
Object.create(1, {});
```

Now the compiler will complain:

> Argument of type '1' is not assignable to parameter of type 'object'.